# How can I Animate a ripped package

Tags: rendering, animation, rigging

I want to animated a package that should get ripped but I have no Idea how I should prepare or animate it.

the package looks like that

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try with an armature, you'll just need to rip an edge (<kbd>V</kbd>):

[image]

[image]